# Is it safe to calculate order totals in React Native?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, react-native

My app gives users the ability to place orders, and I'm wondering how I should calculate their order total.

I could calculate it on the server when they navigate to the checkout page, but then I run into a problem because the customer can add a tip to their order. This means the order total can change in the checkout screen.

Is it safe to calculate the order total when the navigation is performed and then update it in React Native if a tip is added, or should the app reach out to the server every time the order total needs to be changed?

Comment: Surely the app "reaches out" to the server when adding a tip anyway?

Comment: use redux to manage your state but it will take some time